# Publish as a service from ArcGIS desktop to ArcGIS online without basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online-basemaps, publishing

I'm trying to publish a map document as a service from ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 to ArcGIS Online.  It works just fine, except that ArcGIS Online automatically loads in a basemap.  This usually isn't an issue, but I'm working with a map of Io, one of Jupiter's moons.  A basemap of the earth is less than helpful.

I've seen the Javascript code to hide the basemap, but I was just curious if there's any way besides coding to remove the basemap.  I couldn't find a setting in the Publish a Service dialog box.

Is it possible to publish a map document as a service and only get the map document without ArcGIS Online's basemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to create a "Blank basemap" by following the steps outlined at the GisNuts.com blog posting entitled [How to Create a Blank Basemap for ArcGIS Online](https://gisnuts.com/terra/blog/2014/01/28/how-to-create-a-blank-basemap-for-arcgis-online).

> I have a client that is using Esri's basic map application viewer
>   template to serve out the maps that they create on ArcGIS Online from
>   their office server.  Their office is in a somewhat rural location, so
>   their bandwidth is not great (DSL).  They wanted to know if they could
>   just remove the basemap while the map loaded to speed up the load
>   time.  Initially loading the map and subsequent map navigation were
>   painfully slow.  They wanted to be able to turn on a basemap when
>   needed, but for it to otherwise be off.  After doing some research, I
>   came up with a solution that they were quite pleased with.  It is a
>   bit of a hack, but until Esri gives us a blank basemap option, it
>   works.